# Method doesn`t end and prints several times the same output

Tags: java, recursion, methods

After calling a `setup()` method in `checkInput()` this method doesn't complete and starts waiting for completing. If to call `checkInput` several times theres only spreading the queue of the methods. That`s why input print not once, although that's what I need. What should I do to fix it?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class BaseConverter {

    private static final char[] Symbols = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    private static String R;
    private static int p;
    static int numlimit;
    static char letterLimit;
    private int q;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //INPUT DATA
        setup1();
    }

    private static void setup1() throws IOException {

        //ЗАДАЄМО ЗНАЧЕННЯ СЧ
        System.out.print("p=");
        p = DataInput.getInt();

        if(p<=10) numlimit =p-1;
        else letterLimit=Symbols[p-11];

        //SETTING IN WHICH NUMERAL SYSTEM WE`LL BE CALCULATING
        System.out.print("R=");
        String a = DataInput.getString();
        R = a.toUpperCase();
        //CHECH FOR THE CORRECT INPUT
        checkInput(R);
    }

    private static String checkInput(String val) throws IOException {
        String readyNum="";

        for(int i=0; i<R.length(); i++){
            char x = R.charAt(i);
            int n = x-48;

            // IF 'p' IS LESS THAN 10
            if(p<11){

                // IS THIS A LETTER
                if(Character.isLetter(x)){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect data input! Enter again");
                    setup1();
                }

                // CHANGING DOT TO COMMA
                else if(x==46) x=44;

                //CHECK DIGITS
                if(numlimit < n){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect data input! Enter again");
                    setup1();

                }
                readyNum += x;
            }
            // IF 'p' IS MORE THAN 10
            else{
                if(x>letterLimit){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect data input!");
                    setup1();
                }
                else if(x==46) x=44;

                // IF THERE`S A NOT ALPHABETIC/NUMERIC CHARS LIKE !&?$%^@# SO ON
                else if(!Character.isLetter(x) && !Character.isDigit(x)){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect data input!");
                    setup1();
                }
                readyNum += x;
            }
        }
        readyNum=R;
        System.out.println(readyNum);
        return readyNum;
    }
    private static void convertTo10() {

    }

}
```

As I said, debugging I found that there's a queue of the `checkInput()` and `setup()` methods and they all stop only if the right number is here. In the end this right number print so times as times of methods calls...